# How to add a Windows path to the Windows Ubuntu Subsystem path

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a folder in my F drive and I want the bash on Windows Ubuntu Subsystem to point to it.
The Folder is

> F:\Projects\Phrasal

I am not sure how to add the Phrasal directory to my Shell path in the Windows bash.

My Shell path is

> jos@HOME:~$

In other words i would like to have all the files in the phrasal directory to be available in the HOME directory or copy the files into HOME directory

Comment: So do you want to add it to your `PATH` or do you want to navigate to that directory?

Comment: I want to add it to my shell path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I don't understand what do you mean by *Shell path*. You said your Shell path is `jos@HOME:~$`. `jos` is your username and `HOME` is your computer name. `~` indicate home directory.

If you want to access your folder in F: drive then you can do this:

```
cd /mnt/f/Projects/Phrasal
```

This will navigate you to the folder you want. If you want to add it to your `PATH` then do this:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/mnt/f/Projects/Phrasal
```

Comment: I want the files in the phrasal directory to be available in the HOME directory

Comment: To copy all the files from phrasal directory to your home directory:
`cp /mnt/f/Projects/Phrasal/* ~ -R`

Comment: As an advanced solution (if you don't want to copy them over and over again from that location) you could use a symbolic link. `ln -s /mnt/f/Projects/Phrasal/ Phrasal` while being in `~`.

Comment: I want to have the whole windows path (ps: $env:path) available in WSL. Is this possible with a built-in function or do I need the workaround with copying it to PATH var in bashrc?

Answer (score 8):

To add **lasting** params to the $PATH in Ubuntu Bash for Windows 10 you first have to start the bash with the additional param "--login"

> C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe ~ --login

Thanks to https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/219#issuecomment-294390862

After that you can edit your .profile

> nano ~/.profile

There you can add a line at the last position:

> PATH=$PATH:/new/path:another/path